# How can I add schema mark up for multiple holiday resorts?

Tags: schema.org

Our client is a holiday company that offers villa accommodation at a list of different resorts in Menorca. We want to mark up the homepage for the handful of top resorts. Is it possible to mark up one page for multiple resorts do this or would we only be able to mark up one resort per page? I also can't find a schema generator or plugin for resorts, does anyone know if there is one or would we need to write the code ourselves?

Comment: Why the home page?   The home page should usually have markup for your brand.

Comment: What's the goal of this markup?